# Is there any way to run laravel cache, view, route clear in one time?

Tags: laravel

I am building a small app but I always need to clear all caches. How can do it or is there any way to run laravel cache, view, route clear in one time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try `php artisan optimize:clear` to clear the cache.
To clear and rebuild in one command `php artisan optimize`

Comment: The `php artisan optimize` command will clear the caches and rebuild them. so no need to clear them

Comment: Since he asks how to clear the cache, this is the proper way of clearing the cache. Sometime you don't want to rebuild the cache at all

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake, I thought you meant do both,